# Upgrade from CE v1.9.0.1 to CE v.1.9.1.0

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade

I have just scanned through the update documentation, but I'm not quite sure. Is the update from CE v1.9.0.1 to CE v.1.9.1.0 as easy as just using

*System >> Magento Connect >> Magento Connect Manager >> Manage Existing Extensions >> Check for Updates >> (mark all available updates) >> Commit Changes*

in the back office? Or are there additional steps (like database upgrade) necessary?

I only want to update my development environment, not a live shop, so I don't care about additional steps of backups, testing the upgrade on a copy or the likes. I'm still a Magento newbie so please excuse if that process is supposed to be straight forward.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should be able to use this process, and Magento will handle database updates as it processes new package versions on first boot (as per installing extensions).  Alternatively, drop a copy of 1.9.1.0 over the top (download and extract it over your local installation)

Comment: If I just copy over the extracted files from the CE v1.9.1.0 archive, will it still perform necessary database upgrades automatically? I just read through [these](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/upgrading_magento#upgrading_magento_using_the_magentoconnect_manager) instructions for using Magento Connect Manager to upgrade the installation, but I'm not so sure about the mentioned tarball upgrade magento-core/Mage_All_Latest and the described "How to upgrade MagentoConnect Manager". There obviously are more ways to reach the goal, which one is the simplest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Make a complete backup of your site if Magento connect hangs up or you have problems you may need to revert to your backup.

2) Backup your database: You will need this if you upgrade fails. You can then take the backup of your site and the backup of your database and re-create your site at the point in which you started your upgrade.

To be honest, the upgrade will be easier, safer and smoother if you simply copied all the new files into you application. The easiest way is via rsync but you can also use FTP.

```
rsync -avz /new/version/of/magento/ /path/to/your/html/
```

Just remember to make a backup however you decide to upgrade